# What's the logic behind this definition of 'to hold' ?

Tags: legalese, etymology

I'd like to dredge below this (legal?) definition of **to hold**, that differ from the norm.

> 5.6. (Of a judge or court) rule; decide:

Would someone please explain the etymology and the reasoning behind these stricter meanings? Please explain the steps or thought processes, for want of doing so by myself in the future? I tried http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hold&searchmode=none

Comment: I admit I don't understand your question. *Hold* comes from Teutonic *haldan*  *"to watch over, keep charge of, keep, herd, pasture (cattle)"*  (from the OED) from there it is easy to go to the meanings listed in the OED: "to rule (people), guard, defend, keep from getting away or falling, preserve, reserve, keep possession of, possess, occupy, contain, detain, entertain, retain, maintain, sustain’, in which it is now used." Watching over someone is a way to rule over them. But aren't questions of etymology better suited for ELU?

Comment: The standard authority for etymological questions like this is, as Laure indicates, the *OED*. The current online edition requires a subscription, and may not be easily available to you; but for most purposes the first edition is adequate. That is accessible online at the links [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/739/32).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology.  It would fit better on ELU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the steps by which this meaning developed in *OED 1*, s.v. **Hold**, definition **12**:

> **12.** To have or keep in the mind, entertain:
>   **a.** (a feeling, etc.) *Obs.* or *arch*

This is a very old use; *OED* cites *Beowulf* , “Hio..heold heah-lufan wið hæle-Þa breȝo.” [=She held high love toward the prince of heroes]. We still speak of , for instance, ‘holding’ sympathy for someone or some cause.

> ...
>   **b.** (a belief, opinion, doctrine, etc.): To accept and entertain as true; to believe.

For instance, the U.S. *Declaration of Independence*: “We hold these truths to be self-evident”.

> **c.** With obj. clause: To be of opinion, think, consider, believe (*that*)

For instance, “Russell holds that the primary value of philosophy is not in any kind of definite answer, but exists in the questions themselves.”

From there it is a very easy step to

> **e.** Of a judge or court: To state as an authoritative opinion; to lay down as a point of law; to decide.

—for the ‘opinion’ held by the judge, what the Court thinks, is the basis of the decision, which in the common-law tradition is binding upon future judges.